# HTML Textbox Input Tooltip?

Tags: html, tooltip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make an HTML text box show a hint when empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty)

A very simple question. I would like to place a tooltip within a Textbox similar to the StackOverflow log in. I want the word discount on the textbox value and when the user enters a new value, the word "discount" disappears from the Textbox.

Can I do this by myself using events like OnBlur, OnChange, etc (I don't know which)? Or there is something around that is already done?

Thanks

Comment: Its called watermarking.

Comment: [Many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429520/how-do-i-get-placeholder-text-in-firefox-and-other-browsers-that-dont-support-th) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536346/placeholder-for-search-textbox).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that is the name. I'll check later.

Answer (score 6):

As said by *rudeovski*, you can use placeholder in modern browsers.
But for the older one, you'll need a javascript/jQuery fallback.
*Here is a good example:*

http://uniquemethod.com/html5-placeholder-text-with-modernizr-and-jquery-fallback

This will generate placeholder fallback for you automaticly.
 *You simply have to write:*

```
<input type="text" id="discount" placeholder="discount" />
```

**Modernizr** combined with **jQuery** will do the rest for you.
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use placeholder text for this.

```
<input type="text" id="discount" placeholder="discount" />
```

To make it work on all browsers, you need to use jquery/javascript for it.  As far as i know, it doesn't work in IE.